# free cloud data stores that use get/post?

Tags: javascript, hashmap, cloud

I know that there are other key/value stores similar to http://openkeyval.org out there but i cannot remember their names.

Please enlighten me.

i need the following features:

- free
- can be used via 100% clientside code
- fast and easy to integrate with

*edit*:
dropped the security requirement, since its not very important to me and was skewing the answers towards self-hosted solutions.

found another service:
http://rastajs.errorjs.com/

this one is easy to use but seems to mangle my values by removing all the spaces!

Comment: Have you considered building your own simple key-value store on Google App Engine?  There are limitations on how much is free, but they are scalable.

Comment: i have not, mostly because what i want to store is simple json data, and also because i want to spend about 25 mins writing this internal app total.

Comment: Is openkeyval the solution you keep as best solution for now or are there reasons you won't?

Comment: By the way I am really wondering how they (plan to) make money.

Comment: You can check out a service I recently built for this.. https://jsonbin.io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed something like that, so I've built this: [KVStore.io, a simple key/value API based storage service](http://www.kvstore.io)

It's still under heavy development (it's an alpha version...) but I'm using it to store some stuffs (like website marketing forms) and it's working nicely...

Comment: looks awesome! Do i need to sign up to use it?

Comment: Yes.. you have to sign up... there's a post endpoint that allows you to do it.. I've published the Api here: https://www.mashape.com/lordkada/kvstore . Let me know if it works... :-)

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thank you!

Comment: Mashape changed their URL signature, so KVStore can be found here: https://market.mashape.com/lordkada/kvstore

Comment: I know it is late, check whether this is helpful online keyvalye store [http://keyvalue.immanuel.co/] (http://keyvalue.immanuel.co/) with possible developer api..

Comment: Update: kvstore.io docs can be found here now: https://rapidapi.com/lordkada1/api/kvstore

Comment: @Immanuel Your website is actually the one I chose. Great service: simple usage, no annoying sign-up, clean design. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Parse.com's data storage api has a really wonderful jquery library ( https://github.com/srhyne/jQuery-Parse ) that makes it extremely easy to have simple key/value storage from your front-end javascript.

Comment: I spent hours trying to fit a square peg (simple JSON data) into a round hole (Google Cloud Storage/Google Cloud Datastore), then I chanced upon this answer. Totally forgot about Parse, now my app is up and running within minutes!

Comment: I don't think that parse.com is free. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Parse.com was shutdown recently :-/

Answer (score 4):

[OpenKeyval is open-source](https://github.com/shinyplasticbag/openkeyval), so you can host it yourself internally and add whatever access limitations you like.

[CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) is basically OpenKeyval on steroids. It provides a RESTful JSON API than can be accessed from any environment that allows HTTP requests (i.e., JavaScript) but you'll have to host it yourself since there aren't any public-facing CouchDB servers (that I know of).

And since you're looking for a list:

- [Amazon SimpleDB](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)
- [Hypertable](http://hypertable.org/)
- [Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/)
- [Ringo](https://github.com/tuulos/ringo)
- [ThruDB](https://code.google.com/p/thrudb/)
- [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/)
- [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/)

Comment: i am looking for free services i can use, and integrate with *fast*. This is a list of free products. Being somewhat secure is the least of my concerns, since its not even possible in a free public service other than through security through obscurity.

Comment: What's the problem with OpenKeyval? It seems to meet your criteria.

Comment: the problem is that i remember reading about a similar service on hackernews and thinking "i should use this in my next project". I have since forgotten the name of it and am willing to spend 100 points to find it again

Comment: There's now Cloudant and Iris Couch for hosting

Answer (score 3):

[StackMob](https://www.stackmob.com) or [Parse](https://parse.com) if you want a (client-side) JavaScript API with user management, facebook/twitter integration, data store (with geospatial), and push notifications.

StackMob also lets you host your website.

For more flexibility, less service lock-in, and cheaper scalability: I would suggest [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) (though you would likely still use a hosting service like [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com)). CouchDB can host your website, and provides a HTTP API for storing data, to which your client-side JavaScript can make REST calls.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Parse, StackMob and Cloudant, there are other solutions:

- [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) provides a free 100MB cloud backend with REST and JS API,
- [MongoHQ](https://www.mongohq.com) offers 512MB free instance of MongoDB with REST API,
- [Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) with 1GB free storage is another option.