# Store and retrieve high score information online with javascript in Windows 8 app?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I have a simple Windows 8 app written in javascript and I would like to create an online high scores list. I would like to use a free service that would allow me to store and retrieve information online. Is there any free service that would allow me to do this?

**Edit:**

I have found a service that works great. Parse.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024819/free-cloud-data-stores-that-use-get-post

Comment: That is great! Parse was exactly what I was looking for!